# Response.end - page does not respond after file download

Tags: application-pages

I have created an application page to download file. I'm using the following code to download the file. After downloading file if I press the download button again it doesn't respond or post back. I assume calling Response.End() ends the connection between server and client. Is there any work around to this issue.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=output.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(file);
Response.End();
```

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by using the code below (some lines not included), which is in the Page_Load method of the Application page.

The App page is loaded from a content page via a click on an asp:HyperLink control, which has CSS applied to make it look like a button.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
Response.ContentType = "application/download";

...

SPFile file = web.GetFile(fullUrl);
Response.BinaryWrite(file.OpenBinary());

...

Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: Hi Howard, Thanks for your reply. Actually i'm loading the application page via a click of a ribbon item that I created and then on the application page I'm generating a file programmatically and then calling the code above. I don't know how to load the application via a content page.. could you point to some samples

Comment: Well the content page simply hosts a user control, which is defined in the page's layout. This control renders the link. You can do the same thing with a custom web part, or even a standard content editor web part. The following link may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms543497.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The following link was very helpful in understanding the response issue that I was facing. It was solved by setting a few flags.

http://mytechsoup.com/?p=36